# Animation Start on Scroll Top

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working on a website in which a javascript animation is intended to start when the user scrolls into view of the section in which the elements associated with the animation are located. I have used the following function to do so:

```
async startDelay(){
        if(!window.scrollY > document.querySelector('#about')){
            this.start();
        }
        else{
            setTimeout(this.startDelay, 300);
        }
    }
```

The animation isn't starting when I scroll to the element, any ideas as to why?

Comment: What specifically are you asking? Is something not working? You may need to include more information in order for someone to be able to help.

Comment: I'm asking if anyone can see anything wrong with my code. What extra information might be of use?

Comment: what is calling startDelay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has two parts. One is detecting when the element scrolls into view. The other is animating it.

The given code does not work because `async` cannot be used with `setTimeout`. It is already suspicious when an `async` function does not contain `await`. That keyword should be removed if `setTimeout` is desired. The other problem is that `!window.scrollY > document.querySelector('#about')` makes no sense. It becomes `!12345 > document.querySelector('#about')` then `false > document.querySelector('#about')` then `false > SomeKindOfElement`. Something based off `getBoundingClientRect` could be used there instead but there is a better way.

Modern browsers support asking them to notify when the element is scrolled into view using `InteractionObserver`. It is only necessary to call this function once:

```js
// I assume the original code was placed in a class,
// and calls this exactly once on startup after the document is loaded
setup() {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
      observer.disconnect(); // Cleanup
      this.start(); // Start the animation
    }
  });
  observer.observe(document.querySelector("#trigger-on-scroll"));
}
```

The other half of the problem is starting the animation. The modern way to do that is to define styles with `transition` (`animation` for more advanced things) and add a class to the element when the element scrolls into view.

Here is an interactive example with some placeholder content and simple animations:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
      observer.disconnect();
      document.querySelector("#animate-me").classList.add("start-animating");
      document.querySelector("#trigger-on-scroll").classList.add("another-animation");
    }
  });
  observer.observe(document.querySelector("#trigger-on-scroll"));
});
```

```css
header>div {
  padding: 70px;
  background: #faa;
}

header>div:nth-child(even) {
  background: #afa;
}

header>div::after {
  content: " header padding";
}

footer>div {
  padding: 50px;
  background: #faf;
}

footer>div:nth-child(even) {
  background: #aaf;
}

footer>div::after {
  content: " footer padding";
}

aside {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  background: #ff0;
}

.start-animating {
  background: #0f0;
  transition: background 1s;
}

article {
  height: 500px;
  background: #00f;
}

.another-animation {
  background: #aaf;
  transition: background 3s;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
  </header>
  <article id="trigger-on-scroll">
    You saw me!
  </article>
  <footer>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
  </footer>
  <aside id="animate-me">Watch me!</aside>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I took so long to get back to you, it's been a busy week. Thanks for the explanation, very helpful!